# Pinvoke stack imbalance detected

Tags: stack, pinvoke

I have the following function:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, SPoint lParam);
```

It keeps complaining about Pinvoke stack imbalance when the following code executes:

```cs
SendMessage(EventRichTextBox.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, OldScrollPoint);
```

What can cause that issue?

this is my SPoint

```
  private struct SPoint
    {
        public Int32 x;
        public Int32 y;
    }
```

and

```
SPoint OldScrollPoint = default(SPoint);
```

Comment: What is SPoint defined as? It's supposed to be an IntPtr, or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for sure, but one obvious possibility is that you are on a 64 bit machine and `int` is the wrong type for `wParam`. It needs to be a 64 bit value in a 64 bit process.

We also have no idea how you have declared `SPoint`. You are meant to pass a pointer to a [`POINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162805%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) struct. It doesn't look as though you have done that.

The correct signature is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

---

Your edit clarifies that `SPoint` is a struct. This then is clearly wrong. You could simply pass the `SPoint` as an `out` parameter. That would be the simplest solution.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, out SPoint lParam);
```

If you wanted a more general `SendMessage` signature then you should use `IntPtr` as I stated above and use `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.

Comment: yeh sorry the SPoint is struct

Answer (score 1):

The wParam argument should be IntPtr.  But that's not what triggers the MDA, lying about the argument type is fine but you do have to do it correctly.  Structures are passed by reference in the Windows api, declare the lParam argument as `ref SPoint`.   Or `out` if the structure is returned, the case for EM_GETSCROLLPOS.